# .NET Sporadic SQL connectivity issues - network name cannot be found

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, windows, .net-core

So this is something that has been plaguing me on and off for years, however i'm at a loss for what possible avenues I have left to explore.

I have a bunch of .NET applications running on a server that perform various functions, all of these sporadically crash with the following classic error

```
Unhandled exception. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (67): The network name cannot be found.
```

what makes it odd is

- The connection string is a direct IP
- the server is not offline (within 5 seconds of this, another 10 applications ran and used the DB as normal)

Every single instance of this error i can find online, is just people going "whoops put the server name in wrong" or "whoops it wasn't online lol"

Has anybody experienced anything like this or similar?

connection string is below - connection is opened using the default 'SqlConnection' object wrapped in a using

```
uid=username;password=password;server=ip;connection timeout=30;database=db;max pool size=100;
```

Servers are 2016 standard v10.0.14393

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to the SQL _language_. Consider replace the <sql> tag with a one for the dbms you're using, and your question will get adequate attention.

Comment: I wouldn't bet the farm to the experience of random strangers on the internet, but for reliability and performance reasons I'd ditch Named Pipes - the MS-TDS protocol is chatty enough, let alone tunneling it over Named Pipes with all of its flow control and request/response semantics. If all of the applications are running on the same host as SQL Server itself, prefer to use Shared Memory, otherwise prefer to use the TCP/IP client protocol.

Comment: This article is light on detail but a good jumping-off point, [Choosing a Network Protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms187892(v=sql.105)).

Comment: Why not just add a retry to get another connection? Most networks can go down once in a while